# When can I use a power of a Keeper in Adventure Time Fluxx?

Tags: fluxx

Some keepers have powers. Can these powers only be used during the turn that you play the keeper or every turn whilst the keeper is in play?

Answer (score 1):

In the [official rules](http://www.looneylabs.com/lit/rules/adventure-time-fluxx-rules), it states:

> If a keeper has a special power, you must have the card on the table in front of you in order to make use of the power.

So as long as you have the keeper in front of you on the table, you can use its power.